# Where's this dale in Sunrise Hill, Alberta?

Tags: identify-this, landform

1. Is dale/valley the correct [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_landforms)?
2. I chanced on this picture [here](https://www.msn.com/en-ca/money/homeandproperty/what-dollar500000-gets-you-across-canada/ss-BBMzs1L?ocid=spartanntp#image=13). The putative photographer [captioned](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/scenic-hiking-views-sunrise-hill-kananaskis-699727651)

> Scenic hiking views from Sunrise Hill and in Kananaskis Country Alberta Canada

but Googling [`Sunrise Hill`](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sunrise+Hill+SW,+Turner+Valley,+AB+T0L+2A0/@50.6422601,-114.3743455,11.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x5371af8e7bddb905:0x98eb4e5e01551e2d!8m2!3d50.6688996!4d-114.2898384) yielded a street with suburban McMansions.

[image]

Comment: I found quite a lot of information by asking Mr Google "sunrise hill hike alberta" which even brings up the same image you show. Apparently **Sunrise Hill** is aka **Rainy Summit**.

Comment: By the way, "dale" is a synonym for valley, but especially a broad valley.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Powderface+Ridge/@50.8433333,-114.85,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipOrcCTOr80WwlHuPQM9aKV3l_f99m0KhQOy8d0M!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOrcCTOr80WwlHuPQM9aKV3l_f99m0KhQOy8d0M%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i4032!8i3024!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sRainy+Summit+Overlook!3m4!1s0x5370fc99c5197a79:0x430edca2b86f8b95!8m2!3d50.8433458!4d-114.8500013), this photo was taken at the Powderface Ridge, next to the Sunrise Hill.

The Sunrise Hill according to [this page](http://www.playoutsideguide.com/2016/11/sunrise-hill-powder-puff-kananaskis.html) is south-east of the Powderface Ridge. However, it's not shown in Google Maps. Here's a screenshot from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.8307516,-114.8366366,9810m/data=!3m1!1e3) that shows the location of the Sunrise Hill (I added the text):

[image]

The valley you see in the photo is called Elbow Valley.

Comment: beat me to it, I'd gotten similar stockphotos but not the details you found :)

Comment: @MarkMayo been researching this for the better part of an hour, it's actually seems like a good hike.